# Python is not executing an instruction when a certain condition in the if statement is met

Tags: python

The IDLE should print out a certain text to the console when the user enters a certain word in lower case and instead it is executing the else instruction. Any help will be truly appreciated.

```
word = input("enter the secret word:")

flower = "Spathiphyllum"

if word == flower:
    if word.islower():
         print("No, I want a big spathiphyllum!")
    else:
        print("Yes - Spathiphyllum is the best plant ever!")
else: 
    print("Spathiphyllum. Not [input] !")
```

Comment: It works for me. What did you enter

Comment: Which else clause did you end up getting? The outer one?

Comment: Do you mean `print(f"Spathiphyllum. Not {word} !")`?

Comment: I figured out how to fix it check out my posted solution!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are tring to achive.

```
if word == flower:
```

flower is `Spathiphyllum`
So, it the word is the same is flower, how can it be:

`if word.islower():`?

It can't be lower **AND** equal to `flower`, because `flower` start in uppercase, and this is what the nested if try to ask.

If word is like flower then it goes to the else of the inner `if` and it prints out:

```
print("Yes - Spathiphyllum is the best plant ever!")
```

By the way, I think that in here:

```
print("Spathiphyllum. Not [input] !")
```

You mean:

```
print(f"Spathiphyllum. Not {input} !")
```

Comment: I finally got it to work using this code. I think now it is more logical to understand. Thank you anyways!

word = input("enter the secret word:")

flower = "Spathiphyllum"
lowerFlower = lower(flower)

if word == flower:
    print("Yes - Spathiphyllum is the best plant ever!")
elif word == lowerFlower:
         print("No, I want a big spathiphyllum!")
else: 
    print("Spathiphyllum. Not [input] !")

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work using this code. I think now it is more logical to understand. Thank you anyways!

```
word = input("enter the secret word:")

flower = "Spathiphyllum"
lowerFlower = lower(flower)

if word == flower:
    print("Yes - Spathiphyllum is the best plant ever!")
elif word == lowerFlower:
         print("No, I want a big spathiphyllum!")
else: 
    print("Spathiphyllum. Not [input] !")
```

Comment: Make sure to keep an eye on your indentation. It is important in python. The print in the elif is not indented correctly. You could also change the elif to `elif word == lower(flower)`. In Python, its recommended to use snake case (eg. snake_case) vs other naming conventions. You can do it like you did (`lowerFlower`). But just something you should know if you are learning python

Answer (score 0):

So the input would print on the else line, I changed the last two lines to this ....

```py
name = input("Please enter flower name :")

if name == "Spathiphyllum" :
    df = "Spathiphyllum is the best plant ever!"
    
elif name == "spathiphyllum" :
    df = "No, I want a big Spathiphyllum!"
    
elif name == "pelargonium" :
    df = "Spathiphyllum! Not pelargonium!"
         
else:
    print(f"Spathiphyllum! Not {name}!")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
name = input("Please enter flower name :")

if name == "Spathiphyllum" :
    df = "Spathiphyllum is the best plant ever!"
    
elif name == "spathiphyllum" :
    df = "No, I want a big Spathiphyllum!"
    
elif name == "pelargonium" :
    df = "Spathiphyllum! Not pelargonium!"
         
else:
    df = "Spathiphyllum! Not [input]!"
        
print(df)
```